# Azure API Management Styling Guide Admin Page Corrupted

Tags: azure-api-management

For reasons I can't explain, the [Styling Guide page (Styles)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-developer-portal-customize#styling-guide) in the new Azure API Management portal I am working on appears to be corrupted and I don't know how to fix it.

For example, the `COLORS` section is supposed to look like this:

[image]

But now looks like this:

[image]

I did a "Reset content" operation under the Operations menu item (several times) to no avail.  I think this issue started after I did my first "Publish" of my changes, but I am not sure.

How do I fix the style sheet for this admin page?

Comment: Did you try to clean the session in the browser and Ctrl +F5?

Comment: @Igor I cleared my entire browser cache (again) and this time it did indeed work.  If you want to post this as an answer, I'll vote for it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This caching issue happens from time to time. Please clean the session in the browser and Ctrl +F5